# Leitura de array com JSON

Tags: php, json, array

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [xml] => {
        "orders": [ 
            {
                "code":"PedidoTeste-1508156986545",
                "channel":"PedidoTeste",
                "placed_at":"2017-10-16T10:29:46-02:00",
                "updated_at":"2017-10-16T10:29:46-02:00",
                "total_ordered":155.0,
                "interest":0.0,
                "discount":0.0,
                "shipping_cost":0.0,
                "shipping_method":"Correios PAC",
                "estimated_delivery":"2018-02-10T22:00:00-02:00",
                "estimated_delivery_shift":null,

                "shipping_address": {

                    "full_name":"Denis Moura",
                    "street":"Rua Sacadura Cabral",
                    "number":"130",
                    "detail":"",
                    "neighborhood":"Centro",
                    "city":"Rio de Janeiro",
                    "region":"RJ",
                    "country":"BR",
                    "postcode":"20081262",
                    "phone":"21 3722-3902",
                    "secondary_phone":null

                },

                "billing_address": {

                    "full_name":"Denis Moura",
                    "street":"Rua Sacadura Cabral",
                    "number":"130",
                    "detail":"",
                    "neighborhood":"Centro",
                    "city":"Rio de Janeiro",
                    "region":"RJ",
                    "country":"BR",
                    "postcode":"20081262",
                    "phone":"21 3722-3902",
                    "secondary_phone":null

                },

                "customer": {
                    "name":"Denis Moura",
                    "email":"denis@skyhub.com.br",
                    "date_of_birth":"1998-01-25",
                    "gender":"male",
                    "vat_number":"78732371683",
                    "phones":[
                        "21 3722-3902"
                    ]
                },

                "items":[
                    {
                        "id":"CAPR-5001778435-",
                        "product_id":"CA-1172191395-13500",
                        "name":"Carrinho Auxiliar CA-40",
                        "qty":1,
                        "original_price":162.8,
                        "special_price":155.0
                    }
                ],    
                "status": {
                    "code":"book_product",
                    "label":"Pagamento Pendente (SkyHub)",
                    "type":"NEW"
                },    
                "sync_status":"NOT_SYNCED",
                "invoices":[],
                "shipments":[],
                "payments":[ 
                    {
                        "method":"CREDIT_CARD",
                        "description":"Cartao",
                        "parcels":1,"value":155.0
                    }
                ]    
            },    

    [httpcode] => 200
)
```

Esse array veio de uma requisição GET que eu fiz. Ele fica armazenado em $retorno.

```
$url = "https://api.skyhub.com.br/orders";
$retorno = $this->get_b2w($url);
```

Eu na verdade esperava que $retorno viesse como uma string, para dar:

```
$retorno = json_decode($retorno);
```

E receber o seguinte JSON:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "code": "PedidoTeste-1508156986545",
      "channel": "PedidoTeste",
      "placed_at": "2017-10-16T10:29:46-02:00",
      "updated_at": "2017-10-16T10:29:46-02:00",
      "total_ordered": 155,
      "interest": 0,
      "discount": 0,
      "shipping_cost": 0,
      "shipping_method": "Correios PAC",
      "estimated_delivery": "2018-02-10T22:00:00-02:00",
      "estimated_delivery_shift": null,
      "shipping_address": {
        "full_name": "Denis Moura",
        "street": "Rua Sacadura Cabral",
        "number": "130",
        "detail": "",
        "neighborhood": "Centro",
        "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
        "region": "RJ",
        "country": "BR",
        "postcode": "20081262",
        "phone": "21 3722-3902",
        "secondary_phone": null
      },
      "billing_address": {
        "full_name": "Denis Moura",
        "street": "Rua Sacadura Cabral",
        "number": "130",
        "detail": "",
        "neighborhood": "Centro",
        "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
        "region": "RJ",
        "country": "BR",
        "postcode": "20081262",
        "phone": "21 3722-3902",
        "secondary_phone": null
      },
      "customer": {
        "name": "Denis Moura",
        "email": "denis@skyhub.com.br",
        "date_of_birth": "1998-01-25",
        "gender": "male",
        "vat_number": "78732371683",
        "phones": [
          "21 3722-3902"
        ]
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "CAPR-5001778435-",
          "product_id": "CA-1172191395-13500",
          "name": "Carrinho Auxiliar CA-40",
          "qty": 1,
          "original_price": 162.8,
          "special_price": 155
        }
      ],
      "status": {
        "code": "payment_received",
        "label": "Aprovado (SkyHub)",
        "type": "APPROVED"
      },
      "sync_status": "NOT_SYNCED",
      "invoices": [],
      "shipments": [],
      "payments": [
        {
          "method": "CREDIT_CARD",
          "description": "Cartao",
          "parcels": 1,
          "value": 155
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Porém estou recebendo o Array mostrado acima.

Estou tentando printar o nome e email do customer de cada order (no caso desse array só possui 1 order, mas poderiam ter vários).

Estou tentando printar com:

```
foreach($retorno["xml"]->orders as $pedido)
{
   echo $pedido->customer->name;
   echo $pedido->customer->email;
}
return;
```

mas não estou conseguindo. Qual seria a forma correta? Fico recebendo o erro Trying to get property of non-object na linha do FOREACH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa percorrer os pedidos, então o `foreach` deve iterar a lista de pedidos, não de clientes. Provavelmente a "falha" que você citou é um erro dizendo que o *array* `$retorno->xml->orders` não possui o atributo `customers`, então só aí você já deveria ser capaz de identificar o que está errado (já que a mensagem de erro te disse isso).

O correto seria:

```
// Percorre a lista de pedidos:
foreach($retorno["xml"]->orders as $pedido)
{
    echo $pedido->customer->name;
    echo $pedido->customer->email;
}
```

Comment: Estou recebendo o erro Trying to get property of non-object na linha do foreach :/ já tentei dar $retorno = json_decode($retorno); e mesmo assim não deu certo....

Comment: No meu código deu esse erro?

Comment: Sim! ): Não sei o que fazer. O $retorno está vindo de uma requisição GET que estou fazendo

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se muda algo.

Comment: O erro permanece o mesmo.

Comment: Ok, edita a pergunta e adicione o seu JSON e como você está utilizando o `json_decode`.

Comment: Pronto, da uma olhada lá :)

Comment: @InoveCommerce Dado os dados que você colocou, minha primeira solução deveria funcionar: https://ideone.com/JjfGqp. Ou você não colocou corretamente os dados na pergunta, ou você fez algo diferente. Recomendo que você reescreva sua pergunta e detalhe melhor qual é o problema. Por exemplo, tem um `$this->get_b2w($url)` na sua pergunta que está completamente perdido, sem explicação alguma sobre o que é esse método.